# Recursion using a String

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static String repeater(int x, String word) {
   if　(x > 0) {
       System.out.print(word.charAt(0));
   }

   if (x == 0) {
       return "";
   } else {
       return repeater(number-1, x);
   }
```

This code gives me the output I want which is basically taking the first letter of a String and printing it 'x' number of times:

Example:

```
when my 
String = Hello 
and x = 6

HHHHHH
```

My problem is I want this method to work the same way but without the use of the 'System.out.print()' line. Am I going to have to add a second String? If not, what approach should I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I see you need it's recursive.

```
public static String repeater(int x, String word) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return word.charAt(0) + repeater(x - 1, word);
    }
}
```

How is this?

For understanding this recursion, it is working like nested parentheses of Mathematics.

```
"H" + ("H" + ("H" + ("H" + ("H" + ("H" + (""))))))
```

Comment: It has to be recursion unfortunately

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me though! :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting to do. Perfect! Thanks hata !!

Comment: This is out of topic but I just wanted to say that this community is just incredible. You guys are out of this world, keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add second string. And instead of "System.out.print" you can assign value of word.charAt(0) to that variable.

pseudo code-

`String output="";`

below line of code within repeater method

`output=output+convert.tostring(word.charAt(0))`

i.e.:

```
String output="";
public static void repeater(int x, String word) {
  if　(x > 0) {
    output += convert.toString(word.charAt(0));
 }

 if (x == 0) {
   return;
 } else {
   repeater(number-1, x);
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to what you mean. Could you show me instead?